# How to make ragdoll-like physics

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, actionscript, physics, game-physics

I'm looking for a tutorial on how to make ragdoll-like physics. Specifically in flash.
For example: If a guy get's hit, then he goes "flying"... As oppose to him just... disappearing. Where would be the best place for me to find a tutorial, or could you explain the basics of it here?

EDIT: Forget to mention 2-dimensional, not sure if that's a given but...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Developing the physics of an object, or a basic physics engine, is going to require a knowledge of mathematics particularly with vectors and trig. There are loads of good instructions out there dealing with the simulation of objects. That being said here are some good tutorials to get you started:

Basic 2D physics engine, explanation of simulation, and even a break down of vector mathematics you may not be familiar with:

http://www.wildbunny.co.uk/blog/2011/04/06/physics-engines-for-dummies/

Here's one written in C++ but can easily be applied to actionscript:

http://gamedevelopment.tutsplus.com/tutorials/create-custom-2d-physics-engine-aabb-circle-impulse-resolution--gamedev-6331

I would start with these and get familiar with them, they contain the building blocks for a good physics engine and will teach you a lot about the mathematics behind them.

Comment: Thanks! Also, how in depth are these two? I'm just aiming to have a body get scattered when hit by something, is this overkill or would it work?

Comment: Either way it's going to require some of what is explained in these tutorials. They are fairly in depth, but they are broken down into parts so take what you need.